# Mongo Db search in date range

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

this query return 0 records but db contain many within this range

```
  db.player_sessions.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          "date": {
            "$add": [
              "$CreatedOn",
              18000000
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "dateWithOutHour": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          "date": {
            "$add": [
              "$CreatedOn",
              18000000
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "OsAndVersion": "$OsAndVersion",
      "BrandAndModel": "$BrandAndModel",
      "MobileOperator": "$MobileOperator",
      "CreatedOn": {
        "$add": [
          "$CreatedOn",
          18000000
        ]
      },

      "VendorID": "$channel.VendorID"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Type": "Channel",
      "PurchaseType": "Subscription",
 "CreatedOn": {
        "$gte": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1516114950000"
          }
        },
    "$lte": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1531094399000"
      }
    }
  }

    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "Views": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "WatchTime": {
        "$sum": "$PlayedDuration"
      },
      "AverageWatchTime": {
        "$avg": "$PlayedDuration"
      },
      "UniqueUsers": {
        "$addToSet": "$UserID"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "WatchTime": "$WatchTime",
      "Views": 1,
      "AverageWatchTime": "$AverageWatchTime",
      "UniqueUsers": {
        "$size": "$UniqueUsers"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

query return data if date range in $match is removed and please verify if date range implementation is correct in created in section of aggregation and this query is select records from certain date range and group them by type and calculations

Comment: please provide your data samples